# iphone how to I make a uitableviewcellaccessorydisclosureindicator background transparent?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, transparent

Can someone please explain to me how I can make a uitableviewcellaccessorydisclosureindicator's background in a UITableViewCell transparent?

Right now I'm facing this problem:

[alt text http://www.bubl3r.com/disclosure.jpg](http://www.bubl3r.com/disclosure.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

Just found the answer. Turns out it was just 3 lines & having to define my own disclosure indicator .png image with a transparent background:

```
UITableViewCell *bgView = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    bgView.backgroundColor=indexPath.row % 2? [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.95 blue:0.95 alpha:1]: [UIColor whiteColor];
    bgView.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"disclosure.png"]];
    cell.backgroundView=bgView; 


    return cell;
```

Answer (score 4):

In your `UITableView`'s delegate, override the delegate method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`. In there, set the cell's `backgroundColor` property to whatever color, and the accessory view's background color should match.

Comment: This works great is is *much* cleaner than the answer above because it uses the default image so will be updated when Apple updates the OS.

Comment: i tried this solution, but i couldn't get the area behind the disclosure to match my background color.  any ideas?

Comment: I concur - this is much better than working with custom icons just to get a transparent color. This even works in monotouch ;)

Answer (score 3):

More detail from anshuchimala's answer:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];//or any color
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: I was setting cell.contentView backgroundColour and wondering why accessoryView had not the same BG colour. Your post made me realize I should've just set cell.backgroundColour. Thanks.