# MonoTouch.Dialog: Setting Disclosure Indicator Clear in OwnerDrawnElement

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a custom `OwnerDrawnElement` where I override the GetCell to add a Disclosure Indicator, but it is not transparent. How do I make the DisclosureIndicator `transparent` so that the look for the cell comes thru?

```
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell =  base.GetCell(tv);
        cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
        return cell;
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480923/iphone-how-to-i-make-a-uitableviewcellaccessorydisclosureindicator-background-tr